# C++ atomics using memory_order_acquire without a matching memory_order_release

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers, compare-and-swap

Is there any case where we'd want to load an atomic with `memory_order_acquire` without a corresponding store to the same atomic with `memory_order_release`?

For example, if I have this piece of code:

```
std::atomic<uint64_t> state;
std::atomic<uint64_t> count;

// Thread 1
while (true)
{
  auto expected = state.load(memory_order_relaxed);
  auto desired = get_desired(expected);
  if (state.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed) { <----- (A)
    count.fetch_add(1, memory_order_relaxed); <---- (B)
    break;
  }
}


// Thread 2
auto state = state.load(memory_order_acquire); <----- (C)
auto count = count.load(memory_order_relaxed); <----- (D)
```

The `memory_order_acquire` in Thread 2 should prevent the load of `count` from being moved before the load of `state`, but since we use `memory_order_relaxed` everywhere else, am I correct in saying that Thread 2 may see an updated value of `count` that's possibly newer than `state` i.e. see the effects of (B) before it sees the effects of the `compare_exchange` from (A)?

If I wanted the effect of (A) to always be visible to Thread 2 when it loads it in (C), then would I change (B) to `memory_order_release`, use `memory_order_acquire` in (D) and flip the order of (C) and (D)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `memory_order_acquire` in Thread 2 should prevent the load of `count` from being moved before the load of `state`

No. Atomic memory ordering in C++ is not defined in terms of preventing certain operations from being reordered with respect to each other. Instead, it is defined in terms of requiring certain side effects to be visible at certain points. In particular,

- if thread A performs a release-store on an atomic variable,
- and thread B performs an acquire-load on the same atomic variable,
- **and** thread B's acquire-load reads the value that thread A's release-store stored;
- **then**, all side effects performed by thread A prior to the release-store are guaranteed to be observable by thread B after the acquire-load.

If you only have acquire-loads but no release-stores, then there are no such ordering guarantees.

> am I correct in saying that Thread 2 may [...] see the effects of (B) before it sees the effects of the `compare_exchange` from (A)?

Yes.

> If I wanted the effect of (A) to always be visible to Thread 2 when it loads it in (C), then would I change (B) to `memory_order_release`, use `memory_order_acquire` in (D) and flip the order of (C) and (D)?

Yes. Assuming I've understood you correctly, after you've performed the sequence of transformations described, we will have

- in thread 1: a relaxed store to `state` through `compare_exchange_weak` followed by a release store to `count` through `fetch_add`
- in thread 2: an acquire load from `count` followed by a relaxed load from `state`

Assuming the acquire-load from `count` reads the value stored by thread 1, the relaxed load from `state` in thread 2 must observe the value that was stored by thread 1, *or a later value*.

Comment: Do note that `seq_cst` stores count as release operations, you don't need to have actually used `memory_order_release` like the question title asks.  (But if you're bothering to use operations that are only as strongly-ordered as necessary instead of the default, you usually don't need seq_cst for anything.)